# Remove Copyrighted Footer From IONCube Encrypted PHP

Tags: php, css, subscribe, encryption, ioncube

I Have A Code Which Has been encrypted by IONcube and i really couldnt decode it to see the regular codes
i just wanted to remove the footer which contained software copyrighted .
i just paid for the script but i didnt wanted the copyrighted so far
i removed it with display=none code in css for the main page
but i still have a problem
my script is a mail script which send mail to the users 
in the footer of the mails layout i still have the copyright and i want it to be removed
i found that the layout of the mail theme is in index.php file which is encrypted .
how can i remove it from there ?
is there any additional code u suggest ?
can i still use css but in the index.php code ?
the div of mail which i found it by " inspect element " option on firefox is :

> ```
> style="font-size:7pt;text-align:center
> ```

Comment: yes you can use css and hide the copyright div use
display:none!important;

Comment: Try to decrypt your code [Link](http://ioncubedecoder2013.blogspot.in/2013/05/ioncube-decoder.html)

Comment: Thing is if you're permitted to do such thing. If it's a proprietary application all copyright info should be left visible .

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Id of the element you could hide it with css using the property `"display:none"`.

But there is a legal question here. Are you sure you can remove the branding? Ask the seller about it.

Comment: The OP is asking about removing content from an HTML email sent by the encoded script. JavaScript won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it should be possible assuming that the footer is the same in all files but of course you need to be sure you can do this and check your agreement. If you buy script you should always add that you want unencrypted source but it can make this script will be 2 or more times expensive.

Source of output of encrypted file is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
4<br />4294967296<br />65536<br /><div id="footer">This is custom footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So there's a footer in this file which we want to remove.

You need to create .htaccess file in the root directory of your project with content:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php
php_value auto_append_file append.php
```

In prepend.php you have to put:

```
<?php

ob_start();
```

In append.php you have to put:

```
<?php
   $content = ob_get_contents();
   ob_clean();

   mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');



   echo str_replace(
     '<div id="footer">This is custom footer</div>
</body>',
'', 
$content
   );
```

Source of the encrypted file when you run it in browser is now:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
4<br />4294967296<br />65536<br />
</html>
```

So the footer of file has been removed.